# Predicting future IDs used before saving to the DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am saving a complex dataset in Laravel 4.2 and I am looking for ways to improve this.

`$bits` has several `$bobs`. A single `$bob` can be one of several different classes. I am trying to duplicate a singular `$bit` and all its associated `$bobs` and save all of this to the DB with as few calls as possible.

```
    $newBit = $this->replicate();
    $newBit->save();

    $bobsPivotData = [];
    foreach ($this->bobs as $index => $bob) {
        $newBob = $bob->replicate();
        $newBobs[] = $newBob->toArray();
        $bobsPivotData[] = [
            'bit_id' => $newBit->id,
            'bob_type' => get_class($newBob),
            'bob_id' => $newBob->id,
            'order' => $index
        ];
    }

    // I now want to save all the $bobs kept in $newBobs[]
    DB::table('bobs')->insert($newBobs);
    // Saving all the pivot data in one go
    DB::table('bobs_pivot')->insert($bobsPivotData);
```

My problem is here, that I cant access `$newBob->id` before I have inserted the `$newBob` after the loop.

I am looking for how best to reduce saves to the DB.  My best guess is that if I can predict the `id`s that are going to be used, I can do all of this in one loop.  Is there a way I can predict these `id`s?

Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think of a solution but not the best one i guess ==> before the loop get the greatest id in bobs table then in the loop you can do this `$newBob = $bob->replicate(); $newBob->id = ++$greatestId;` hope that help :)

Comment: is bobs to bobs_pivot one to one relationship?

Comment: This might help if you haven't already looked into it: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the bobs first and then use the generated ids to insert the bits. This isn't a great solution in a multi-user environment as there could be new bobs inserted in the interim which could mess things up, but it could suffice for your application.

```
    $newBit = $this->replicate();
    $newBit->save();

    $bobsPivotData = [];
    foreach ($this->bobs as $bob) {
        $newBob = $bob->replicate();
        $newBobs[] = $newBob->toArray();
    }
    $insertId = DB::table('bobs')->insertGetId($newBobs);        

    $insertedBobs = DB::table('bobs')->where('id', '>=', $insertId); 
    foreach($insertedBobs as $index => $newBob){ 
        $bobsPivotData[] = [
            'bit_id' => $newBit->id,
            'bob_type' => get_class($newBob),
            'bob_id' => $newBob->id,
            'order' => $index
        ];
    }
    // Saving all the pivot data in one go
    DB::table('bobs_pivot')->insert($bobsPivotData);
```

I have not tested this, so some pseudo-code to be expected.